# Open port 80 in Linux does not work

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, port-forwarding

I'm trying to open port 80 in linux by using gufw.
Here's my rules:

```
-A ufw-user-output -d 192.168.0.100/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-output -d 192.168.0.100/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

And here's the output when I check the `ufw status`

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
192.168.0.100 80           ALLOW       Anywhere                                 

192.168.0.100 80           ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
```

I already set port forwarding from my tp-link router with this setting (check no. 2):

[image]

But when I check my open port with [Port Checker Tool](http://www.portchecktool.com/), it still tells me that port 80 is closed. Can you help me how to solve my problem? thank you.

Comment: Do you have anything _listening_ on port 80?

Comment: by the way: you use 2 times "ufw-user-output" - but nothing for "input". That seems the "problem" why you not able to access service port 80. I think there must be another chain called "ufw-user-input" ...

Comment: (1) Why are you opening udp/80 here? (2) Your title says "open port 80... does not work" but your question states that _port forwarding to 80 does not work_.  The first step is to check locally whether or not tcp/80 is open on the target machine, before adding the complication of port-forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

"uncomplicated firewall" (gufw) is using iptables to configure ip filters.
So you should understand ip filter and how it works.
iptables knows the following tables for filter ip:

```
filter- the default table. it is designed for pure filtering. if you do not user "-t  it is the default used one.
nat - this tables is used for network address translation. like it will be use for DSL or WLAN routers. also it is used to combine one public address with a private network e.g. 192.168.x.x.
mangle  - this tables is used for packet manipulation.
raw - this table could be used for exceptions on connection tracking.
```

All of this tables uses chains:

```
INPUT       - tables:filter, mangle : the rules on this chain will be executed on all packets going to a local process (e.g. ip address / port )
OUTPUT      - tables:filter, nat, mangle, raw   : the rules on this chain will be executed on all outgoing packets (from a local process) 
FORWARD     - tables:filter, mangle : the rules on this chain are used to all routed packets
PREROUTING  - tables:nat, mangle, raw   : the rules on this chain are used for all packets BEFORE the will be routed 
POSTROUTING - tables:nat, mangle    : the rules on this chain will be execute after a routing operation happend
```

The "bad" thing is that gufw uses user-defined chain which will be used inside the default table. so far so good but as long as you don't understand how iptables works it may be harder to take a look under the gufw hood.
So let me show how this simple rule - and this is what you looking for - could be implemented using native iptables from the command line

What you need is:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT   #1
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -p tcp --sport 80 -j ACCEPT  #2
```

#1 This will insert a chain to the default table "filter" on the first position of the tables chain "INPUT" and allows (accept) tcp ip traffic coming from anywhere going to port 80
#2 This will insert a chain to the default table "filter" on the first position of the tables chain "OUTPUT" and allows (accept) tcp ip traffic coming from a local process on port 80 and going outside to any destination ip address and any port number.

So I hope this will help to transfer you knowledge to us gufw also or maybe you could throw gufw and use native iptables - cause it's not that complicated for 98% of all use cases :-)
Also maybe this link will help to come along with ufs - the command line tool beside gufw: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/firewall.html